# Expo - Error on "eas build --platform ios" - createInfoPlistPluginWithPropertyGuard) is not a function

Tags: ios, react-native, build, expo, eas

I've always used expo to build my iOS applications, recently I had to make some updates on my code and when I went to generate a new build, the following error message appeared:

```
 TypeError: (0 , _iosPlugins(...).createInfoPlistPluginWithPropertyGuard) is not a function
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

My dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/nunito": "^0.2.2",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    "@unform/core": "^2.1.6",
    "@unform/mobile": "^2.1.6",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "eas-cli": "3.0.0",
    "expo": "^46.0.0",
    "expo-app-loading": "~2.1.0",
    "expo-av": "~12.0.4",
    "expo-checkbox": "~2.2.0",
    "expo-file-system": "~14.1.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~13.3.1",
    "expo-sharing": "~10.3.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.16.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.14.7",
    "expo-video-thumbnails": "~6.4.0",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.6",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.5.0",
    "react-native-iphone-x-helper": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-masked-text": "^1.13.0",
    "react-native-modal-selector": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-modal-selector-searchable": "^2.1.4",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.11.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.10.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  }
```

any idea what it could be?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Try:

```bash
yarn install @expo/config-plugins
```